# Python EWM(Expential Weighted Moving Average) with filtered condition in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'd like to make filtered EWMA in pandas.

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import pandas_datareader.data as web

    gg = web.DataReader('GOOG', 'yahoo', start = '2015-01-01', end = '2018-12-31')
    ln_gg = np.log(gg['Adj Close'])
    d_ln_gg = ln_gg.diff()
```

Now I made daily return of an equity of Google.

Next thing I would like to do is that making **'filtered historical volatility'** with using **EWMA(Exponential Weighted Moving Average)**.

I know 'EWM' in pandas makes above EWMA, e.g. `d_ln_gg.ewm(alpha = 0.94).mean()`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0nCo.jpg)

However, above alpha option counts whole period of time series. I need limited period of EWMA.

But, span option is also not satisfying as I would like to apply smoothing decay effect like 'alpha' option. **'span'** option is apply same effect designated period.

So, I want make EWM with alpha option with using only prior 30 days of time series. Is there any other way to do ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you are not understanding what EWM does. I suggest read more closely what it means.
1. If you would like to use only 30 days, slice your data. If you would like to use rolling 30 day, then span=30 kind of does this for you (even though it will always have traces of the previous data; albeit negligible).
2. If you want to have some special filters, consider writing your own ewma function (that's best)
3. Not really clear what you mean by: "I need limited period of EWMA."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, you said that .... span option can apply what I means to do. However I understand that “span” option apply that equivalent weight, right? I would like to apply different weight effect.  Thanks

Comment: if it were applying equivalent weight, then it's not an EWMA anymore and simple a mean, right? So I am not really following what you are saying.

Comment: After reading more closely I understood the EWM option. Yes, you right. I think I misunderstood that option. Well.... Come to think of it, if I want specialized EWMA -- e.g EWMA(t, n) : EWMA using prior n days at time t : X(t-1), X(t-2)... X(t-n), -- It would be best way to get this by using this formula, EWMA(t,n) = normal EWMA(t) - normal EWMA(t-n-1) * lambda^(n). Again, thanks for advising.